# odd stuff attached to browser request

Tags: nginx

From my nginx log:

```
    444 MYIPADDRESS - - [27/Apr/2017:16:30:42 +0000] "GET /mypage.htm?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1kILLh8XTAhUl2oMKHZTaBq0Q_B0IGjAC HTTP/1.1" 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/23.1.148956103 Mobile/14B100 Safari/600.1.4" "-"
```

I've been ignoring this for months, but this request keeps showing up periodically. First of all, I have no code to process anything after a question mark in the URL request. My website is 90's era. So there is no reason for such a request to show up.

Second, I use nginx to capture request oddities that make no sense for my website and the question mark is in a set of characters that I don't use, hence it triggers my nginx map. I was getting what I assume to be fuzzing hacks, that is weird stuff thrown at the web server, hence the trap.

Comment: Is there a question here? The [question mark is URI syntax](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4) identifying the query portion of a URI. Not sure if that's what you're asking, though.

Comment: The question is somewhat answered. Basically some program is adding that query to the URL. That is my website doesn't generate the query.  Currently my nginx conf is set up to not answer URL requests with queries since I don't generate them. Often the query is related to some hacker trying to find a proxy on my server, which I don't have, but that doesn't stop them from generating the requests.

Comment: Since the query string is part of the URI, it could also be that the url including query is a link that someone copied and then put on a website or stored as a bookmark.

Answer (score 2):

This is Google referrer syntax. If the referer is google.com, that's most likely Google passing information to your site that can be used in their analytics engine. They're giving you information that may be of value to you if you want to understand where your traffic is coming from. You can see these query strings for yourself by running a google search. Here's the top URL from a search for "bigbird":

```
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6z7rgncbTAhVkx1QKHTFqCAcQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBig_Bird&usg=AFQjCNGxF83OLvD4tz5pvmnOVDaUxKl-lA&sig2=jQ6_DmAznp08tHgRB0DyWw
```

Here, sa=t and ved=0ahUKEwj6z7rgncbTAhVkx1QKHTFqCAcQFggnMAA

If you're running google analytics on your website, that will get converted into a click count for traffic from a web search, additionally it came from the search result, not from an ad, and possibly other information. [These folks](https://moz.com/blog/decoding-googles-referral-string-or-how-i-survived-secure-search) have done extensive reverse engineering on what these query parameters represent if you want to do a deep dive into decoding what information google passes in these query strings.

Comment: OK. I know google does that redirection "thing" , but never looked into it. I did a copy link and see the data after the question mark. However the IP was not google. And thus far this is the only hit I in that manner. I get plenty of google referrals, but nothing with the extra fields. I don't run google analytics. It is more like something is stuck and the same request keeps getting sent. Anyway, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I noticed most google requests are of the form "GET /mypage.htm HTTP/1.1" 257 "http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc yada yada yada. So there is something odd that those google parameters are showing up in the request field rather than the referral field